# select request in php with errors

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to select data from mysql database with code in php but always i have errors.`

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";
$db = "test";
$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db)
or die ("connexion impossible");
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("selection de la base échoué");
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE username= '$username' AND     password='.$password'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($num == 1) {
while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$output = $list;
echo json_encode($output);
}
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\wamp\www\projet\connect.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\wamp\www\projet\connect.php on line 11
```

Comment: You're missing a `$` on line 11 (`query = ...`). Also, don't put data from $_POST to SQL query directly, see [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Comment: @amalch : Its 30 minutes, someone post the answers and you have not gone through it?? Was your question really URGENT??

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE username= '$username' AND     password='.$password'");
```

with

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE username= '".$username."' AND     password='".$password."'");
```

You have missed the $ before variable query, and with some string concatenation problems

And please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of deprecated mysql_*

Answer (score -1):

there is extra dot before `$password` in mysql query and `query` should be `$query` as `$query` is variable.

```
query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE username= '$username' AND     password='.$password'");
```

should be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE username= '$username' AND     password='$password'");
```

Comment: @skwee : I know SQL injection is important, BUT amalch provided that query so I went ahead... GOT THAT???